# When the Android package private directory will be create?

Tags: android

Android private data directory like this `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/package.name/files`.
I want to know when this kind of directory will be created?

Comment: I think when your install APK on an android phone create these files. if these files by your create, when you write code ```new File()```

Comment: @Javad Dehban  No. Creating a File instance does nothing. Then you would need .mkdirs().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When app invoke getExternalFilesDirs(), this function will try to mkdir for app's private directory. It send a RPC to vold service to make the dir

getExternalFilesDirs() -> ensureExternalDirsExistOrFilter() -> sm.mkdirs() -> StorageManagerService.mkdirs() ->  Vold.setupAppDir()